# Why is value of a value class as its hashCode "not a good idea"?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode

The very last paragraph of **Item 9** of **Effective Java, 2nd Edn, J. Bloch** 
says that, for value classes like `Integer`, `String`, `Date` etc, 
*returning a function of the the exact value of that class as 
the `hashCode` isn't a good idea*.

So, the class `Integer` returning the `value` of the integer it represents as the `hashCode` of its instance isn't all so good.

Neither is the [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) of `String` returning an integer value directly mapped from the overall content, i.e., the characters that the `String` instance has.

These `hashCode()`-s clearly comply with the contract.

To me, it seems to be a good idea rather than a bad one-- the `hashCode`-s vary as the values vary across objects, and these `hashCodes` are "normalized" before they are spread out into the buckets of a `HashMap`/`HashSet`-- so that the `hashCode`-s of the entries do not form a bias on which bucket the entry will go in.

What am i missing here - what makes mapping the class value directly to `hashCode` a "bad idea"?

TIA

//===========================

EDIT

pls also see comments under Steve Siebert's answer in relation to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it's saying is that those javadoc specification say exactly how the hashCode is created.  By doing so, applications can now depend on this always to be true...and now those implementations can never change the way that the hashCode is generated.

It doesn't mean that you shouldn't derive your hash from your values...just don't tell people how you do this in your specification =)

Comment: agree to that. but the solution to this should be forcing a principle that 
"the `hashCode` shdn't be used as an indicator/functional substitute of `value`", rather 
than getting in between that nice relationship between `value` and `hashCode()` and thus between `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, a hashCode can in practice be treated as one that returns a "less intelligent/lossy" representation of the actual value of the object - susceptible to the birthday paradox.  But, really, a hash doesn't necessary *need* to have a relationhsip with value...hashCode needs to always return the same int value for the same object (however this is defined by you) so the object can be found in the expected bucket.  Normally this is done by hashing one/more values of the object...that makes sense.  But, if it could be done with, say...magic...then who am I to judge? =)

Comment: clinging `hashCode` to `value` 
is likely to ensure "if two objects aren't equal, than neither are their hashCodes" and that's a good thing to have for evenly distributed entries across hash buckets-- although it's not a requirement by the contract. 
i neither saw nor can think of a better way of doing this.

Comment: Oh, i totally agree...but I always reserve a space for someone smarter than me to come up with something better =)

Answer (score 3):

The [full quote](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf) is

> Many classes in the Java platform libraries, such as `String`,
>   `Integer`, and `Date`, **include in their specifications the exact value
>   returned by their `hashCode` method** as a function of the instance value.
>   **This is generally not a good idea, as it severely limits your ability
>   to improve the hash function in future releases**. If you leave the
>   details of a hash function unspecified and a flaw is found or a better
>   hash function discovered, you can change the hash function in a
>   subsequent release, confident that no clients depend on the exact
>   values returned by the hash function.

Emphasis mine. The book is just stating that it is generally considered bad practice to reveal implementation details in a specification. This makes it resistant to change.

The fact that it was implemented as returning an exact value (for `Integer`) or some calculated value (for `Date` and `String`) is not bad.

Answer (score -1):

The Java API does just that, it returns the integer.

```
Integer t = ...;
t.intValue() == t.hashCode(); // true
```

I have the same book at work. I'll look at it on Monday.

If you're really worried, implement the [FNV-1a](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) hash:

```
    int hash = 0x4C1DF00D;
    hash = (hash ^ value) * 0x01000193;
```

Comment: I wonder why the downvote? I was planning on coming to the same conclusion as @SotiriosDelimanolis, but I have the book elsewhere and I didn't know it's available for free online.